# Access log files of an Virdi AC 7000 Fingerprint terminal

Tags: android, terminal, fingerprint

I need to access the logfiles of an Virdi AC 7000 Fingerprint terminal. There exist 2 SDKs, the UCBioBSP SDK to communicate directly with the device and the UNION COMMUNITY Server SDK which probable only functions in combination with UNIS server (please correct me if I am wrong as the documentation was rather fuzzy on that detail). The UCBioBSP does not provide the functionality to download logs and my client does not want to use UNIS. Is there another way to download the logs from the terminal? As the UNIS server can access them there should be another way to download them (since it runs on android). Maybe ftp, web services or something else. Any advice is apreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the VIRDI sample code(UCSAPI), provided in C#, C++ or VB.
When you "Start Server", It will open a Listening on port 9870.
The VIRDI AC7000 will connect with this server.
Then you send the command to get the logs, as you can see in the image below.
[image]

Comment: Where can we download the SDK? could you provide us the link?